# New ActiveMQ Installation Runs Out Of Memory After 30 Minutes

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, redhat

We have a fresh installation of ActiveMQ 5.9.1 running on Red Hat Linux. With no outside connections, no queues, and only the default topic on the system, the process runs out of memory (1GB allocated at startup with "-Xms1G -Xmx1G") after about 30 minutes, even with absolutely no activity. I initially ran into this problem with version 5.10.0, and downgraded to 5.9.1 to see if maybe it was something introduced in the new build.

Literally, all I did was:

```
tar xzf apache-activemq-5.9.1-bin.tar.gz
mv apache-activemq-5.9.1-bin activemq
cd activemq
bin/activemq start
```

Using "top", I noted that it started with about 150MB of real memory used, and it continued to creep upward. Once top showed it with 1.1GB, there were several heapdump, core, javacore and trace files in the base directory. The javacore files all state:

```
Dump Event "systhrow" (00040000) Detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError" "Java heap space" received
```

Has anyone else encountered this? How did you fix it?

**UPDATE 2014-08-22**

"java -version" yeilds:

```
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6470sr6fp1-20140108_01(SR6 FP1))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.7.0 Linux amd64-64 Compressed References 20140106_181350 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R26_Java726_SR6_20140106_1601_B181350
JIT  - r11.b05_20131003_47443.02
GC   - R26_Java726_SR6_20140106_1601_B181350_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20140106_181350)
JCL - 20140103_01 based on Oracle 7u51-b11
```

I'm starting to think the IBM JVM may be the problem.

**EDIT 2014-08-29**
Replaced the IBM JVM with the standard Oracle JVM and updated ActiveMQ to 5.10.0, but still have the problem. No connections to the server, one queue with no messages on it. Using the Eclipse Memory Analyzer, the Leak Suspects Report shows 197 instances of org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagedTransportConnection consuming approx. 500MB of memory out of 529MB total. Not sure what this means or how to fix it.

Comment: I suggest you state what version of Java you have and any indication of trouble in your activemq log file.

Comment: Have you used any heap analysis tools to attach to the JVM and see where the memory is being allocated?

Comment: Do you have messages in a dead letter queue?

Comment: @pconrey did you try to decrease the maximum number of connections allowed? also try to use visualvm?